# How to correct "undefined reference" error in compiling OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have downloaded Eigenfaces algorithm in c++ from [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) official website and I've compile it with this command :

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` facerec_eigenfaces.cpp -o opencv
```

But i get these errors:

```
/tmp/cc0CsJ0b.o: In function `norm_0_255(cv::_InputArray const&)':
facerec_eigenfaces.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
facerec_eigenfaces.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
facerec_eigenfaces.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `cv::normalize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int, int, cv::_InputArray const&)'
facerec_eigenfaces.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
facerec_eigenfaces.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
facerec_eigenfaces.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `cv::normalize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int, int, cv::_InputArray const&)'
```

I don't copy all of theme here but they are all are "undefined reference" and my OpenCV version is the same as the link I've mentioned.

Output of (pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) :

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Comment: What's the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` when you call it from your shell prompt?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added the output,thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hypothesis.

Try to move your linker flags to the end of the command:

```
g++  facerec_eigenfaces.cpp -o opencv `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

See also: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: Thanks. it works. could you explain (in simple words) why it should be at the end?

Comment: @chosipa In short, the rule *"libraries come after objects that use them"* is enforced by many GCC distributions to link shared libs only as they are needed. In your case object file `facerec_eigenfaces.o`, being produced from source file `facerec_eigenfaces.cpp`, depends on OpenCV libs (exact list is given by a `pkg-config` command), and thus libs should go after that file. You could also notice very same pattern in `pkg-config` output: for example, X11, pthreads and other Linux system dependencies go after dependent OpenCV libs. See linked Q&A for detailed explanations.